# How do I limit the items FirebaseRecyclerAdapter pulls from the server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using the tutorial project and can't understand how to limit the number of items pulled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with either a `DatabaseReference` or with a `Query`. When you use a `DatabaseReference` the adapter will show all data at that location. E.g. (from the [FirebaseUI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#create-custom-firebaselistadapter-subclass)):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference chatRef = ref.child("chat_messages");

mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(this, 
                                         Chat.class, 
                                         android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, 
                                         chatRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(chatMessage.getName());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(chatMessage.getText());

    }
};
messagesView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

To only show the last 5 chat messages, you'd create a query and pass that into the adapter:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference chatRef = ref.child("chat_messages");
Query recentMessages = chatRef.limitToLast(5);

mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(this, 
                                         Chat.class, 
                                         android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, 
                                         recentMessages) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(chatMessage.getName());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(chatMessage.getText());

    }
};
messagesView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

There's a lot more you can do with Firebase Database queries. Read the [documentation on sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for more.

Comment: Thank you friend. I'm new to Firebase and enjoying it so far.
I saw that i can limit when in query, just didn't think that i can separate the query from the constructor.